# Hide the <front> item in the main menu

Tags: routes

I want to remove the link to the homepage from the main menu.

I can delete it with:

```
menu_link_delete(NULL, "<front>");
```

But I am worried about needing to undo that at some point in the future, or causing problems when some module expects that link to exist.

It looks like `menu_link_save` allows marking a menu item as "hidden", but I can't figure out how to get the mlid so that it knows I want to edit an existing menu item.

I have tried calling `menu_main_menu`, but the result doesn't appear to have a `main_menu['<front>']` element.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Features module let me export the menu, at which point it was easy to set 'hidden' => '1' on the 'main-menu:' link.